# What is the meaning of this linear scale of angles on this 1951 map of Iceland from the U. S. Army Map Service (AMS C762)?

Tags: maps, topography, angles, iceland

On the [U.S. Army Map Service (AMS C762)](http://islandskort.is/en/category/list/41) 1:50,000 maps made of Iceland 1948–1951, there is a scale marking at the top which shows degrees, I suspect angles.  In the image below it shows 25°–29°.  It increases to the left, which suggests it might refer to degrees longitude west, but the numbers are not correct; the map covers 18°W–18°30'W.  It's not a magnetic declination either, which is shown elsewhere on the collar in the usual way.  Other maps in the series have a similar scale in the same place, but the numbers may be different.  What does this angle scale mean?

[image: Bláfjöll map extract]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe it is actually used to generate a Magnetic north line, using the reference point P on the bottom edge of the map. At least that's how I interpreted the statement in the declination legend (shown below) which seems to refer to the scale you mentioned.

I picked a sheet a random. At the time the map was done the angle was 31.25 (+ 2.5 degrees?) degrees from grid north, very close to the middle of the equivalent scale I saw in that sheet.

[image]

[image]

Presumably they added a few degrees either side to extend the usability of the map into future years.

Comment: On closer inspection, it looks like the 29° line and the 34° line are not actually parallel.  Cool.